# Updating a JSONB object with multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have the following query -

```
update ms
set data = json_build_object('OTHER', 29.8, 'other_PCT', '', 'MEDI_PCT', 11.4,  'COMMERCIAL', commercial_percent, 'NPI Commercial_PCT', '')
from ms
join mkt
on ms.data_id = mkt.id
join mix pm
on pm.npi = mkt.npi
and ms.data_id = 6000
and dataset_id = 20
```

The error I am getting is

```
table name "ms" specified more than once
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.6) do not repeat the table to be updated in the FROM clause:

```
update ms
  set data = json_build_object('OTHER', 29.8, 'other_PCT', '', 'MEDI_PCT', 11.4,  'COMMERCIAL', commercial_percent, 'NPI Commercial_PCT', '')
from mkt
  join mix pm on pm.npi = mkt.npi
WHERE ms.data_id = mkt.id --<< this replaces your original join between ms and mkt
  and ms.data_id = 6000
  and dataset_id = 20
```